ONB for an unbounded self-adjoint operator
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $D:\mathrm{Dom}(D) \to H$ a densely defined operator on $H$. We further assume that $D$ is closed and self-adjoint. Does it follow, like in the fin-dim case, that $H$ admits an ONB whose elements are eigenvectors of $D$? I guess this is almost certainly not true, but I would like an example.
This implies that, via functional calculus, we can speak about the square root of $D$, or more precisely

This is not even true for bounded operators. Say, $T: L^2([0,1]) \to L^2([0,1])$ given by $(Tf)(x) = xf(x)$ is bounded, self-adjoint, and has no eigenvector. To get an ONB of eigenvectors, you need $T$ to be compact. Regardless, functional calculus still works. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Bounded_self-adjoint_operators

@DavidGao You don't need it to be compact, but you do need it to have no continuous spectrum.

@RobertIsrael Of course. When I said “you need $T$ to be compact”, it was not intended to be a necessary condition, just a common sufficient one. (Technically, not having continuous spectrum is not necessary either. An injective diagonal compact operator on $\ell^2$, for example, has an ONB of eigenvectors, but it does have continuous spectrum, namely ${0}$.)
